# Dialogflow ES test area don't recognize the configured intents and calls "Default Fallback Intent"

Tags: dialogflow-es

I am following the Google basic course to create a chatbot with Dialogflow and have already created an agent, create an intent and then I am assigning phrases via the Training option to this test intent called "Schedule Appointment" and then "approving" then in the training screen.
Then I check if they are in the "intent", check if the variable is OK, then if the response is correctly configured and all looks great there, then I test with exactly the same phrase I have just added to the intent but it keeps ignoring it (maybe this has something to do: https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/intents-training-phrases#example_and_template_modes

What I am doing wrong?

I am attatching images of the intent, the training of the intent and of the test result (try it now).

Thanks,

[image]

[image]

[image]

The test should return me the response, since I am  using the same exact phrase the agent is already trained in the intent and I have a configured response, but it returns me the "I don't understand you" response from default Fallback, instead of calling the "Schedule Appointment" Intent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like a transient issue in some projects, a Google cloud public issue has been addressed [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/272577292) which discusses the same issue and Dialogflow engineering team is working on it. You can +1 to vote and show that you're affected by it.
All future updates on the issue will be shared on the public issuetracker thread.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that test chat is not working. Things are currently being changed in functionality of dialogflow ES ans that seem to be affecting some parts of training area.
In production it works correctly so I am doing the testing in a production environment and works perfectly well.